# PHPStorm: PHP code inside HTML tags

Tags: php, html, wordpress, ide, phpstorm

I just changed for PHPStorm (I was a Coda user). I must confess that I am currently very happy but I have a big problem. I work a lot with Wordpress with lots of .php files with both PHP and HTML inside. The problem is that I lose my PHP syntax highlighting (and by the way the auto-Completing code, etc...) when I write PHP Code inside HTML tags.

Here's a picture to explain it.

[image: PHP syntax highlighting problem]

The HTML syntax highlighting is OK but no PHP.

Do you have any idea? Thank you very much!

Comment: 1) Have you tried `File | Invalidate Caches...` yet? 2) Does this issue is reproducible in brand new empty project? 3) Please provide full file content that has such problems (I have re-typed what you have on a screen (instead of just copy-paste (but you have not provided such option, unfortunately)) and it looks OK for me so far. 4) What PhpStorm version do you use exactly (build number) ?

Comment: Wonderful. Solution 1 worked! Thank you.

Comment: @LazyOne Ouch, works the first 10sec after opening, then back to the screenshot above. (version 7.1 build #PS-133.326)

Comment: Well... 1) Please try with all 3rd party (not bundled by default) plugins disabled 2) Check `idea.log` for possible hints (`Help | Show Log in ...`) 3) Backup and delete your project settings (`PROJECT/.idea` subfolder) and re-configure this project from scratch 4) Backup and delete (or just rename) your IDE settings (https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23358108) and start from scratch.

Comment: 5) If still nothing (same behaviour even after deleting ALL settings, IDE and Project ones) then submit new ticket to Issue Tracker at http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WI **P.S.** But would be good to have some simple demo project (or at very least a whole file) to reproduce. **P.P.S** Please try EAP build -- http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/PhpStorm+Early+Access+Program

Comment: @LazyOne Thank you! Fixed the problem by deleting all the settings and restart.

Comment: What settings BTW -- IDE or project ones? P.S. You may restore most of the IDE options from a backup copy (keymap, colors etc -- they extremely unlikely to have any effect on such IDE functionality)

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by deleting all the PHPStorm settings and reset to factory default by restarting the software.

On MacOSX :

```
rm -rf "$HOME/Library/Preferences/WebIde70"
rm -rf "$HOME/Library/Caches/WebIde70"
rm -rf "$HOME/Library/Application Support/WebIde70"
rm -rf "$HOME/Library/Logs/WebIde70"
```